# Policy to stress preferrable syntax

Tags: compiling, best-practices

### Question

Assume someone wrote a LaTeX document using my package some time ago. I want to let him know that his code should be updated.
The idea is to allow outdated syntax by the LaTeX compiler but giving the writer a hint of possible improving his code.

What is the best way to implement this response? Assuming the change is at the macro (usage) level.

#### Example

There is a somewhat extreme example of what should not be used anymore (but this question should not repeat the statements like this):

- Avoid `eqnarray` http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf

Why is there no policy used in a case like this described example?

Comment: Is the syntax change at the package (loading) level, or at the macro (usage) level?

Comment: If it's not a problem to keep the deprecated code in the package, I usually keep it but issue a package warning when it's used.  A more extreme way is to disallow the deprecated code unless some explicit command or package option is given.

Comment: Load `amsmath` and then use `\atop`. See the warning issued on the console when compiling.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, 'Why is this not used in a case like this?'. What is 'this'? and what is 'a case like this'? Do you mean, why aren't there TUG Boat articles explaining why you shouldn't use other deprecated packages or syntax?

Comment: @Werner: I was not aware that there were also changes possible at the package (loading) level. Might be result in another question...

Comment: @cfr: I hope my edit yesterday clarifies your questions.